# How to toggle "wake on lan" using AppleScript

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, macos-sierra

On a Mac, I know I can toggle "wake for network access" in System Preferences.

But I want to be able to toggle it using a script (AppleScript, bash...)

Does anyone know what that command would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work, but it exposes your password:

```
do shell script "sudo pmset womp 1" user name "YOURUSERNAME" password "YOURPASSWORD" with administrator privileges
```

Adjust your username and password and let me know if it works for you.